# Web Server/Technology to work with Raster-Imagery Data

Tags: raster, web-mapping, design, image-service

I am in the process of designing a web application which will allow the end users to load raster imagery data (size range from 300 MB to 500 MB) as a back ground map and a corresponding OLD JPEG image for which data needs to be edited.
**Example**, the latest imagery data will have a DAM which needs to be added on the OLD JPEG map, supporting data.

Web page **Performance** is the key concern over here and I am open to any technology (including Big Data) if it can be leveraged in any way.

If performance becomes a bottleneck for web application then an alternative suggestions for Application Visualization will be a big help. At the end of the day, I want to provide a platform where end users can access huge size raster images to process over the web.

Comment: I see that you have some special needs but could you make a pros/cons list about some existing, same kisnd of projects? Like Map Warper http://mapwarper.net/ and Old Maps Online http://www.oldmapsonline.org/.